# Photoblog in TYPO3

Tags: php, typo3

I am using Photoblog extension in TYPO3 but keep getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 
'C:/xampp/htdocs/testpage/t3lib/class.t3lib_htmlmail.php' 
(include_path='C:/xampp/htdocs/testpage/typo3/contrib/pear/;.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\testpage\typo3conf\ext\photoblog\pi1\class.tx_photoblog_pi1.php on line 92
```

Can you please help me out with this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a working example to send an email with swiftmailer in TYPO3. $replyemail holds the e-mail address and $replyname the name in plain text the same holds true for $toemail and $toname.

```
$mail = t3lib_div::makeInstance('t3lib_mail_message');
$mail->setFrom(array($replyemail => $replyname));
$mail->setTo(array($toemail => $toname));
$mail->setSubject('Text');
$mail->setBody('Text');
$mail->addPart('Text');

foreach ($pdf as $k => $filename)
{
   if (file_get_contents($filename))
   {
       $mail->attach(Swift_Attachment::fromPath($filename));
   }    
}
$mail->send();
```

Comment: Thanks, that error is disappeared now. But now i am not seeing photoblog extension on the page. Am i missing something. I am new to typo3. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1):

class.t3lib_htmlmail.php has been removed from TYPO3 4.7. So you can downgrade to TYPO3 4.5 or  you can patch your extension on your own.

There is some information about the new API: http://buzz.typo3.org/teams/core/article/your-first-blog/

Comment: There is some information about the new API: ... if he is able to write php, he probably can patch that extension.